# Concept of a SaaS system

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, asp.net, saas

Good evening, I developed a system that behaves in the SaaS format, where the client only registers and already has access to use, in it I used a unique identifier for each client and they all use the same structure, PHP files and the same database . So far so good, because the domain does not change, that is, everyone uses www.lalalaetc.com.br/app and the system separates everything by the unique identifier, however, I would like to develop a virtual store from it, only there would be a difference, the domain, that is, I believe the principle is the same, use a unique identifier for each store, but my doubt is how I will make it so that when someone accesses the store the domain is addressed correctly and load the id of my client? What is the way forward and what do I need to research to do such a feat?

Comment: It sounds like you want to develop a multi-tenant application. In this case, you could uses sub-domains, for example `tenant.lalalaetc.com.br.app`, where the word tentant is replaced with a string unique to each tentant. When the request comes into the server, you can parse out the sub-domain, passing it to a function that searches your API/Database by this tentent subdomain

Comment: Great! 
That's right, you may wish to post your comment in reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to develop a multi-tenant application.

In this case, you could uses sub-domains, for example `tenant.lalalaetc.com.br.app`, where the word `tenant` is replaced with a string unique to each tenant.

When the request comes into the server, you can parse out the sub-domain, passing it to a function that searches your API/Database by this tenant subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

i managed to handle the tenant with the folomming steps:

1. i cloned de the parse server source and i added a new middleware named "tenantConfig"
2. in that middleware i intercepts the requests and i get one specific header that i named "x-parse-tenant" and i use the value of that header like a database name
3. so i modify the datapase adapter and then resent it to the requetes and do next() to continue the process
4. so in the client lib or the requests i provide a "x-parse-tenant" header

you can see details in the screenshots
its not perfect i know :D

[image]
[image]